# JPA HQL: SELECT new Object with byte array in the constructor

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jpa, hql

Guys I hope that someone can help me, first of all sorry for my english.

I'm trying to do a query like this:

```
SELECT new com.enterprise.entity.ObjectExample(oe.id, oe.image) FROM ObjectExample
```

and I have a Constructor like this:

```
public ObjectExample(Long id, byte[] image){
    this.id = id;
    this.image = image;
}
```

But in my eclipse keep showing this error: "No constructors can be found that match the argument types."

It's compile normal and the code is running ok, but i'd like to ignore this error in my eclipse or make a constructor in another way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The temporary solution that I found was setting the error for warning to every Invalid or Incomplete JPQL queries.

To do this in Eclipse Luna I follow this instructions:

1 - "Window" / "Preferences"
2 - "Java Persistence" -> "JPA" -> "Errors/Warnings"
3 - "Invalid or incomplete JPQL queries:" set to "Warning".

But this isn't the solution at all.

Comment: Can you write any successful ObjectExample query at all? For example `SELECT oe FROM ObjectExample oe`?